# Multishift operation

Tags: c++, x86, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bmi

How to implement without loop an operation on bitmasks, which for two bitmasks `a` and `b` of width `n` gives bitmask `c` of width `2 * n` with following properties:

- `i`-th bit in `c` is set only if there is `j`-th bit in `a` and `k`-th bit in `b` and `j + k == i`

C++ implementation:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>

#include <x86intrin.h>

std::uint64_t multishift(std::uint32_t a, std::uint32_t b)
{
    std::uint64_t c = 0;
    if (_popcnt32(b) < _popcnt32(a)) {
        std::swap(a, b);
    }
    assert(a != 0);
    do {
        c |= std::uint64_t{b} << (_bit_scan_forward(a) + 1);
    } while ((a &= (a - 1)) != 0); // clear least set bit
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::bitset< 64 >(multishift(0b1001, 0b0101)) << std::endl; // ...0001011010
}
```

Can it be reimplemented without loop using some bit tricks or some x86 instructions?

Comment: Have you checked what assembly a compiler *actually* generates when building with optimizations enabled? Are you *sure* you actually *need* to hand optimize this? Is it time critical? Is it called often? Why is this important? If it's not critically important and a bottleneck, then just write readable code instead of obfuscating it with micro optimizations.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It is time critical. It used to calculate sumset for subset sum problem. Background is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051732/boolean-convolution-using-integer-multiplication/49053489#49053489).

Comment: The `std::cout` is probably taking orders of magnitude more time in that code than all the other lines combined.

Comment: @JesperJuhl seems you can't understand abstract question.

Comment: The abstract question would be better written as a function that takes two `uint32_t` args and returns a `uint64_t`, not a program that prints a compile-time constant result.  Then you could look at the compiler-generated asm with optimization enabled (at least for the case where it doesn't inline into a caller with one of the operands being a constant).

Answer (score 6):

This is like a multiplication that uses OR instead of ADD. As far as I know there is no truly amazing trick. But here's a trick that actually *avoids* intrinsics rather than using them:

```
while (a) {
    c |= b * (a & -a);
    a &= a - 1;
}
```

This is very similar to your algorithm but uses multiplication to shift `b` left by trailing zero count of `a`, `a & -a` being a trick to select just the lowest set bit as a mask. As a bonus, that expression is safe to execute when `a == 0`, so you can unroll (and/or turn the while into do/while without precondition) without nasty edge cases showing up (which is not the case with TZCNT and shift).

---

`pshufb` could be used in parallel table-lookup mode, using a nibble of `a` to select a sub-table and then using that to multiply all nibbles of `b` by that nibble of `a` in one instruction. For the multiplication proper, that's 8 `pshufb`s max (or always 8 since there's less point in trying to early-exit with this). It does require some weird setup at the start and some unfortunate horizontal stuff to finish it off though, so it may not be so great.

Comment: @Orient: on Skylake, `bsf` has 3 cycle latency and only runs on port 1, i.e. the same performance as `imul`.  So BMI1 `blsi` to feed `imul` should have about the same performance as `bsf` to feed `shlx`.  And better performance than `bsf` to feed `shl`, because variable-count shifts without BMI2 are 3 uops on Intel CPUs.

Comment: @Orient: Your problem is very close to a carryless multiply ([`pclmuludq`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/PCLMULQDQ), but you want `or` instead of `xor`.  (A carryless multiply is one where `xor` replaces `add` in the standard shift-and-add; `xor` is add-without-carry.)  IDK if it's possible to use `pclmuludq` as part of this; probably not :(

Comment: I was thinking about the `a + b = (a ^ b) + 2(a & b) = (a | b) + (a & b)` identities, trying to figure out if I could combine `pclmuludq` and normal multiplication in some way to get to OR-ed partial products, but I got nowhere with that..

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is tagged with BMI (Intel Haswell and newer, AMD Excavator and newer), I assume that
AVX2 is also of interest here. Note that all processors with BMI2 support also have AVX2 support. 
On modern hardware, such as Intel Skylake, a brute force AVX2 approach 
may perform quite well in comparison with a scalar (do/while) loop, unless `a` or `b` only have very few bits set.
The code below computes all the 32 multiplications (see Harold's [multiplication idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49057302)) 
without searching for the non-zero bits in the input. After the multiplying everything is OR-ed together.

With random input values of `a`, the scalar codes (see above: Orient's question or Harold's answer) 
may suffer from branch misprediction: The number of instructions per cycle (IPC) is less than the IPC 
of the branchless AVX2 solution. I did a few tests with the different codes. It turns out that 
Harold's code may benefit significantly from loop unrolling. 
In these tests throughput is measured, not latency. Two cases are considered:
1. A random `a` with on average 3.5 bits set. 2. A random `a` with on average 16.0 bits set (50%).
The cpu is Intel Skylake i5-6500.

```
Time in sec.
                             3.5 nonz      16 nonz  
mult_shft_Orient()             0.81          1.51                
mult_shft_Harold()             0.84          1.51                
mult_shft_Harold_unroll2()     0.64          1.58                
mult_shft_Harold_unroll4()     0.48          1.34                
mult_shft_AVX2()               0.44          0.40
```

Note that these timing include the generation of the random input numbers `a` and `b`.
The AVX2 code benefits from the fast `vpmuludq` instruction: it has a throughput 
of 2 per cycle on Skylake.

---

The code:

```
/*      gcc -Wall -m64 -O3 -march=broadwell mult_shft.c    */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

uint64_t mult_shft_AVX2(uint32_t a_32, uint32_t b_32) {

    __m256i  a          = _mm256_broadcastq_epi64(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(a_32));
    __m256i  b          = _mm256_broadcastq_epi64(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(b_32));
                                                           //  0xFEDCBA9876543210  0xFEDCBA9876543210  0xFEDCBA9876543210  0xFEDCBA9876543210     
    __m256i  b_0        = _mm256_and_si256(b,_mm256_set_epi64x(0x0000000000000008, 0x0000000000000004, 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000001));
    __m256i  b_1        = _mm256_and_si256(b,_mm256_set_epi64x(0x0000000000000080, 0x0000000000000040, 0x0000000000000020, 0x0000000000000010));
    __m256i  b_2        = _mm256_and_si256(b,_mm256_set_epi64x(0x0000000000000800, 0x0000000000000400, 0x0000000000000200, 0x0000000000000100));
    __m256i  b_3        = _mm256_and_si256(b,_mm256_set_epi64x(0x0000000000008000, 0x0000000000004000, 0x0000000000002000, 0x0000000000001000));
    __m256i  b_4        = _mm256_and_si256(b,_mm256_set_epi64x(0x0000000000080000, 0x0000000000040000, 0x0000000000020000, 0x0000000000010000));
    __m256i  b_5        = _mm256_and_si256(b,_mm256_set_epi64x(0x0000000000800000, 0x0000000000400000, 0x0000000000200000, 0x0000000000100000));
    __m256i  b_6        = _mm256_and_si256(b,_mm256_set_epi64x(0x0000000008000000, 0x0000000004000000, 0x0000000002000000, 0x0000000001000000));
    __m256i  b_7        = _mm256_and_si256(b,_mm256_set_epi64x(0x0000000080000000, 0x0000000040000000, 0x0000000020000000, 0x0000000010000000));

    __m256i  m_0        = _mm256_mul_epu32(a, b_0);
    __m256i  m_1        = _mm256_mul_epu32(a, b_1);
    __m256i  m_2        = _mm256_mul_epu32(a, b_2);
    __m256i  m_3        = _mm256_mul_epu32(a, b_3);
    __m256i  m_4        = _mm256_mul_epu32(a, b_4);
    __m256i  m_5        = _mm256_mul_epu32(a, b_5);
    __m256i  m_6        = _mm256_mul_epu32(a, b_6);
    __m256i  m_7        = _mm256_mul_epu32(a, b_7);

             m_0        = _mm256_or_si256(m_0, m_1);     
             m_2        = _mm256_or_si256(m_2, m_3);     
             m_4        = _mm256_or_si256(m_4, m_5);     
             m_6        = _mm256_or_si256(m_6, m_7);
             m_0        = _mm256_or_si256(m_0, m_2);     
             m_4        = _mm256_or_si256(m_4, m_6);     
             m_0        = _mm256_or_si256(m_0, m_4);     

    __m128i  m_0_lo     = _mm256_castsi256_si128(m_0);
    __m128i  m_0_hi     = _mm256_extracti128_si256(m_0, 1);
    __m128i  e          = _mm_or_si128(m_0_lo, m_0_hi);
    __m128i  e_hi       = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(e, e);
             e          = _mm_or_si128(e, e_hi);
    uint64_t c          = _mm_cvtsi128_si64x(e);
                          return c; 
}


uint64_t mult_shft_Orient(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    uint64_t c = 0;
    do {
        c |= ((uint64_t)b) << (_bit_scan_forward(a) );
    } while ((a = a & (a - 1)) != 0);
    return c; 
}


uint64_t mult_shft_Harold(uint32_t a_32, uint32_t b_32) {
    uint64_t c = 0;
    uint64_t a = a_32;
    uint64_t b = b_32;
    while (a) {
       c |= b * (a & -a);
       a &= a - 1;
    }
    return c; 
}


uint64_t mult_shft_Harold_unroll2(uint32_t a_32, uint32_t b_32) {
    uint64_t c = 0;
    uint64_t a = a_32;
    uint64_t b = b_32;
    while (a) {
       c |= b * (a & -a);
       a &= a - 1;
       c |= b * (a & -a);
       a &= a - 1;
    }
    return c; 
}


uint64_t mult_shft_Harold_unroll4(uint32_t a_32, uint32_t b_32) {
    uint64_t c = 0;
    uint64_t a = a_32;
    uint64_t b = b_32;
    while (a) {
       c |= b * (a & -a);
       a &= a - 1;
       c |= b * (a & -a);
       a &= a - 1;
       c |= b * (a & -a);
       a &= a - 1;
       c |= b * (a & -a);
       a &= a - 1;
    }
    return c; 
}



int main(){

uint32_t a,b;

/*
uint64_t c0, c1, c2, c3, c4;
a = 0x10036011;
b = 0x31000107;

//a = 0x80000001;
//b = 0x80000001;

//a = 0xFFFFFFFF;
//b = 0xFFFFFFFF;

//a = 0x00000001;
//b = 0x00000001;

//a = 0b1001;
//b = 0b0101;

c0 = mult_shft_Orient(a, b);        
c1 = mult_shft_Harold(a, b);        
c2 = mult_shft_Harold_unroll2(a, b);
c3 = mult_shft_Harold_unroll4(a, b);
c4 = mult_shft_AVX2(a, b);          
printf("%016lX \n%016lX     \n%016lX     \n%016lX     \n%016lX \n\n", c0, c1, c2, c3, c4);
*/

uint32_t rnd = 0xA0036011;
uint32_t rnd_old;
uint64_t c;
uint64_t sum = 0;
double popcntsum =0.0;
int i;

for (i=0;i<100000000;i++){
   rnd_old = rnd;
   rnd = _mm_crc32_u32(rnd, i);      /* simple random generator                                   */
   b = rnd;                          /* the actual value of b has no influence on the performance */
   a = rnd;                          /* `a` has about 50% nonzero bits                            */

#if 1 == 1                           /* reduce number of set bits from about 16 to 3.5                 */
   a = rnd & rnd_old;                                   /* now `a` has about 25 % nonzero bits    */
          /*0bFEDCBA9876543210FEDCBA9876543210 */     
   a = (a & 0b00110000101001000011100010010000) | 1;    /* about 3.5 nonzero bits on average      */                  
#endif   
/*   printf("a = %08X \n", a);                */

//   popcntsum = popcntsum + _mm_popcnt_u32(a); 
                                               /*   3.5 nonz       50%   (time in sec.)  */
//   c = mult_shft_Orient(a, b );              /*      0.81          1.51                  */
//   c = mult_shft_Harold(a, b );              /*      0.84          1.51                */
//   c = mult_shft_Harold_unroll2(a, b );      /*      0.64          1.58                */
//   c = mult_shft_Harold_unroll4(a, b );      /*      0.48          1.34                */
   c = mult_shft_AVX2(a, b );                /*      0.44          0.40                */
   sum = sum + c;
}
printf("sum = %016lX \n\n", sum);

printf("average density = %f bits per uint32_t\n\n", popcntsum/100000000);

return 0;
}
```

Function `mult_shft_AVX2()` uses zero based bit indices! Just like Harold's answer.
It looks like that in your question you start counting bits at 1 instead of 0.
You may want to multiply the answer by 2 to get the same results.

Comment: Why not just `_mm256_set1_epi32`?  Does explicitly writing `_mm256_broadcastq_epi64(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(a_32))` compile better on something?  Although it should be fine, and with `-march=skylake-avx512`, the compiler should probably still be able to optimize it down to `vpbroadcastd ymm0, eax` instead of separate movd/broadcast.  Or if the value started in memory (after inlining), hopefully the compiler could optimize away the `mov` and broadcast directly from memory (as cheap as a `movd` load).

Comment: BTW, `vpunpckhqdq` is the best choice for that step of a horizontal OR.  Saves 1 byte of code size to leave out the `imm8` shift count of `vpsrldq`.  Alternative: `movq` / `pextrq` and use integer `or`, but that's more total uops (`pextrq` is 2 uops).

Comment: @harold Indeed I didn't try the unrolled loop. This is fixed now. Unrolling helps a lot!

Comment: @PeterCordes What I actually wanted is not `_mm256_set1_epi32` but
`_mm256_set_epi32(0, a_32, 0, a_32, 0, a_32, 0, a_32)`. 
Another possibility would be `_mm256_set1_epi64x((uint64_t)a_32)`, but
the `_mm256_broadcastq_epi64(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(a_32))` leads to the best results,
[see godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/g/krCK55).
Although there might be no advantage at all after inlining, I admit.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fixed the `vpunpckhqdq` in the code, thanks.

Comment: @wim: Oh, that makes sense.  I missed the 64-bit vs. 32-bit issue, which should have been obvious with the widening multiply.  And wow, all 3 compilers make really braindead code (integer load / `vmovq` / `vbroadcastq`) with a memory operand https://godbolt.org/g/Tx34Ue for the "more natural" `_mm256_set1_epi64x((uint64_t)a_32)` way of writing it.  I also tried adding `a_32++;` to simulate already-zero-extended case, and yes unfortunately `_mm256_broadcastq_epi64(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(a_32));` does defeat gcc/clang `-march=skylake-avx512`.  They fail to use `vpbroadcastq ymm0, rdi`, unlike ICC.

Answer (score 3):

OK, let's try to find the clever bit trick, i.e. an implementation that preferably:

1. Exploits hardware bit-level parallelism whenever possible
2. Does not use branching or conditional execution that can't be deduced at compile time
3. Does not require look-up tables (which violate 1 & 2) or relies on lengthy unrolled code with lots of magic constants

The problem you describe has the form of a linear convolution of the two bit sequences, with the peculiarity that the addition operator is the OR boolean function instead of the more common XOR (used in carry-less multiplication) or the binary addition with carry used in normal binary multiplication.

In pseudocode:

```
for (0<=i<=2*n)
    for (0<=k<=min(n,i))
        c[i] |= a[i-k] & b[k]
```

If we assume the entries of $a$, $b$ and $c$ to be binary digits, and the entries of $p$ to be wide enough to represent the intermediate sums, we can transform the problem into a convolution over regular arithmetic (without carry), followed by a conversion of every nonzero array element of the result into a boolean.

```
for (0<=i<=2*n)
    for (0<=k<=min(n,i))
        p[i] += a[i-k] * b[k]
for (0<=i<=2*n)
    c[i] = (p[i]>0)
```

This simplifies the problem because the first operation has the structure of a polynomial multiplication, which in turn can be mapped onto several disjoint integer products as long as we handle any potential carry spills carefully. This way we can vastly speed up our solution using a regular hardware multiplier.

There are a few more things to consider to write a fast implementation, but I will spare you the boring details. Assuming you are targeting a x86 CPU with BMI2 extensions, the following code should perform significantly faster than any naive loop-based implementation.

```
// OR carry-less product
uint64_t clmul_or(uint32_t n, uint32_t m) {

    // interleave input bits with zeros
    uint64_t nn = _pdep_u64(n, 0x5555555555555555);
    uint64_t mm = _pdep_u64(m, 0x5555555555555555);

    // further split inputs into {4n} and {4n+2} bits
    // this results in each element being 4 bits apart from the next
    uint64_t n0 = (nn& 0x1111111111111111);
    uint64_t n1 = (nn& 0x4444444444444444);
    uint64_t m0 = (mm& 0x1111111111111111);
    uint64_t m1 = (mm& 0x4444444444444444);

    // each of the four partial products is a padded linear
    // convolution of 2 16-bit sequences
    __uint128_t p00 = __uint128_t(n0) * __uint128_t(m0);
    __uint128_t p01 = __uint128_t(n0) * __uint128_t(m1);
    __uint128_t p10 = __uint128_t(n1) * __uint128_t(m0);
    __uint128_t p11 = __uint128_t(n1) * __uint128_t(m1);

    // combine odd/even partial results
    p01 |= p10;
    p00 |= p11;

    // reduce consecutive 4-bit blocks
    p01 |= p01>>2;
    p00 |= p00>>2;

    p01 |= p01>>1;
    p00 |= p00>>1;

    // select bits and interleave the result
    p00 = p00 & ( (__uint128_t(0x1111111111111111)<<64)^0x1111111111111111 )
        | p01 & ( (__uint128_t(0x4444444444444444)<<64)^0x4444444444444444 );

    // extract interleaved bits
    uint64_t p = _pext_u64(uint64_t(p00    ), 0x5555555555555555)      // 32 lo bits from product
               | _pext_u64(uint64_t(p00>>64), 0x5555555555555555)<<32; // 32 hi bits

    return p;
}
```

I haven't fully tested the code yet, but I hope it will illustrate the core ideas.

There is one potential bug I haven't addressed in the name of clarity and brevity, which happens when both bit sequences simultaneously have all odd or all even bits set. This will generate a middle sum of partial products of 32, which is not representable within its 4-bit boundary, producing a wrong result and a carry spill into the next block.

This is simple to test for and fix if necessary. On the other hand if we know in advance either mask to have a width <31 bits, or if either or both of the inputs are guaranteed to be minimally sparse (as we would expect from most practical uses of a convolution) we can skip testing for the edge case.

64-bit multiplication (even 64x64->128 bit) is almost or as fast as add/sub in modern CPUs, while boolean and shift operations are usually performed four at a time. The performance of _pext_u64 and _pdep_u64 is also high and somewhere in between both cases.

Comment: *x86 CPU with BMI2 extensions* - other than Zen 1 or 2 or Excavator; AMD had very slow microcoded `pext`/`pdep` until Zen 3.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, I was precisely looking this up. There are of course ways around it, considering how regular the algorithm is.

Comment: Another way to interleave bits with zeros is `pclmulqdq` with itself ([Interleave bits efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72268150)), which is fast on modern CPUs, and at least ok on all CPUs that have it.  It can even do both 32-bit integers at once.  (Or keep them separate since shuffle + extract probably costs more than a second clmul, although having `n` and `m` in different halves of the same SIMD register could perhaps be useful for the later masking work.  Or broadcast `n` and `m` into different SIMD vectors so clmul gives us 2 copies, allowing different masks for hi and lo.

Comment: Worst case, it is possible to do it at a cost of 4 ands, 4 shifts and 4 ors per pdep/pext instruction if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Hrm, on x86 (and presumably most SIMD ISAs) we need scalar for the 64x64 => 128-bit widening multiplies, unless we want to emulate that with 3x 64x64 => 64-bit AVX-512 multiplies (which are themselves multi-uop except on Zen 4).  Unless that's separable into multiple 32x32 => 64-bit elements for `pmuludq`.  If so, then we can keep things in vectors the whole way through, except maybe for the final `pdep` packing.  Is that somewhat similar to what wim's answer is doing with `_mm256_mul_epu32` (`vpmuludq`) without clmul?

Comment: No, as far as I can tell wim has unrolled the while loop in Harold's solution into batches of four and computed 4x 32x32->4x 64 bit products per 256-bit SIMD instruction, which leads to <=8 iterations of the unrolled loop.
I haven't given it much more thought, but there are surely similar solutions in the same line, and ways to exploit SIMD parallelization.

Comment: @PeterCordes To implement this for SIMD with 32-bit integer multiplication it's possible to use a number-theoretic transform over some cyclotomic polynomial and compute all 7 or 8 products in one 8x32 = 256-bit parallel instruction.
It would be a bit elaborate but not much more than dealing with SIMD intrinsics. It is doable should it be necessary.